# TinyMCE - how to not autoenable?

Tags: tinymce

TinyMCE - how to not autoenable?

Few year ago there was an "ask:false" setting for TinyMCE, editor was enabling after clicking on textarea and confirming, but now seems not to work. Any ideas?